# Display number of retweets of a blog post

Tags: php, cakephp, count

I was wondering if anyone has a link to any information regarding building in Twitter Mention functionality into a website like here, http://paul.boagworld.com/?page=2, where each post dispays the number of times it has been mentioned on twitter.

Many thanks,
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website uses the following widget: http://www.backtype.com/widgets/tweetcount